# Magento Products disappear due to stock 0 But stock Options not available

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, stock, magento1.9.3

I have set Stock management Yes for configurable product but have only three options as shown in the screenshot, no option to enter quantity. 
[image]

Comment: Let us know what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For configurable products it works a bit different.
The configurable product becomes out of stock if the simple products associated to it become out of stock.
You cannot fill in a quantity for the configurable products.

Comment: I am not much aware about magento but i purchased a theme and they demo content was set with same configurations. if you say i can sent you admin details.

Comment: never send strangers admin details. :). Look in the "Associated products" tab when editing a product and check if at least one of the products that show up there is in stock. Read more about configurable products here: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html